# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘iterator’ with no type

Tags: c++, generics, templates, build, compilation

I am trying to build/run an old C++ system. I've already been able to built it in Ubuntu 9.10 with g++4.4

Now I'm trying to build in Ubuntu 8.04 with g++4.2. And I am getting the following errors:

```
stringmap.h:353: erro: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘iterator’ with no type
stringmap.h:353: erro: extra qualification ‘stringmap<_Tp>::’ on member ‘iterator’
stringmap.h:353: erro: expected ‘;’ before ‘begin’
stringmap.h:354: erro: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘iterator’ with no type
stringmap.h:354: erro: extra qualification ‘stringmap<_Tp>::’ on member ‘iterator’
stringmap.h:354: erro: expected ‘;’ before ‘end’
stringmap.h:386: erro: no ‘typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::begin()’ member function declared in class ‘stringmap<_Tp>’
stringmap.h:386: erro: template definition of non-template ‘typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::begin()’
stringmap.h:398: erro: no ‘typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::end()’ member function declared in class ‘stringmap<_Tp>’
stringmap.h:398: erro: template definition of non-template ‘typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::end()’
In file included from Ccolumn.h:7,
                 from Ccolumn.cpp:1:
intmap.h:395: erro: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘iterator’ with no type
intmap.h:395: erro: extra qualification ‘intmap<_Tp>::’ on member ‘iterator’
intmap.h:395: erro: expected ‘;’ before ‘begin’
intmap.h:396: erro: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘iterator’ with no type
intmap.h:396: erro: extra qualification ‘intmap<_Tp>::’ on member ‘iterator’
intmap.h:396: erro: expected ‘;’ before ‘end’
intmap.h:429: erro: no ‘typename intmap<_Tp>::iterator intmap<_Tp>::begin()’ member function declared in class ‘intmap<_Tp>’
intmap.h:429: erro: template definition of non-template ‘typename intmap<_Tp>::iterator intmap<_Tp>::begin()’
intmap.h:441: erro: no ‘typename intmap<_Tp>::iterator intmap<_Tp>::end()’ member function declared in class ‘intmap<_Tp>’
intmap.h:441: erro: template definition of non-template ‘typename intmap<_Tp>::iterator intmap<_Tp>::end()’
Ccolumn.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Ccolumn::finish_vector_norm()’:
Ccolumn.cpp:427: erro: ‘class intmap<Ccolumn*>’ has no member named ‘begin’
Ccolumn.cpp:427: erro: ‘class intmap<Ccolumn*>’ has no member named ‘end’
Ccolumn.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Ccolumn::updateCommonColumnNameList(std::string, int)’:
Ccolumn.cpp:461: erro: ‘class intmap<bool>’ has no member named ‘begin’
Ccolumn.cpp:461: erro: ‘class intmap<bool>’ has no member named ‘end’
```

Both stringmap and intmap seems to be having the same problem. The lines the are giving the error are:

```
stringmap<_Tp>::iterator begin();
stringmap<_Tp>::iterator end();
```

Here is the code for stringmap.h (its long):

```
/******************************************************************************

 A hashed associative array.  This version is string-keyed.

 Features:

 - values are templated and hence generic
 - smart sizing and linear probing, based on optimal primes as described at
   http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/GoodHashTablePrimes.html
 - comes with iterator
 - exists() and defined() calls, a-la perl
 - resizing, both upwards and downwards

******************************************************************************/

#ifndef _STRINGMAP_H__
#define _STRINGMAP_H__

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "hash.h"

using namespace std;

// string key special values 
//
#define VACATED "???"
#define EMPTY "!!!"

// the following expects a string argument x
//
#define OCCUPIED(x) ((x != EMPTY) && (x != VACATED))

// the stringmap class
// 
template <class _Tp> class stringmap {
protected:
    vector<string> _keys;
    vector<_Tp> _values;

    unsigned int probe;     // linear probing increment

    unsigned int size;      // array size allocated for storage
    unsigned int size_idx;  // index of current size in hash primes table
    unsigned int minsize;   // min and max array size
    unsigned int maxsize;               

    unsigned int filled;    // used cells in the array

    _Tp undef_val;          // value of template type to return for undefined
                            // index value.

    unsigned int total_lookups;
    unsigned int total_attempts;

    unsigned int hash_func( string );   // the hash function

    // hash table position getter (w/probing).  _set = 1 if the goal is to 
    // set a value (changes behavior for vacated tombstones). basically
    // all of this fanciness enables us to avoid scanning the entire table 
    // when looking for a non-stored key.
    //
    unsigned int index_of( string _key, int _set);  

    void grow();            // grow the table up to the next level
    void shrink();          // shrink the table down to the next level

public:

    unsigned int index_of( string );    // this version assumes _set = 0

    // an iterator
    //
    class iterator {

    protected:

        // container we are connected to
        stringmap<_Tp>* parent;

        int index;  // index into the stringmap

        // increment index to next populated hash entry (or end)
        void increment() {
            if (!parent) return;

            if (index == parent->last_index()) 
                index++;
            else 
                for (string key = EMPTY; index < parent->last_index() && !OCCUPIED(key); ++index, key = parent->key_real(index));
        }

        // decrement index to next populated hash entry (stops at begin)
        void decrement () {

            if (!parent) return;

            int i = index;
            for (string key = EMPTY; i > 0 && !OCCUPIED(key); --i, key = parent->key_real(i));

            // only change index if stopping point is populated.
            if (OCCUPIED(key_real(i))) {
                index = i;
            }
        }


    public:

        // constructors
        iterator() : parent(NULL), index(0) {}  
        iterator(int _index) : parent(NULL), index(_index) {}   
        iterator(stringmap<_Tp>* _parent) : parent(_parent), index(0) {}
        iterator(stringmap<_Tp>* _parent, int _index) : parent(_parent), index(_index) {}

        // iterator scan operations
        void operator+=(int _n) { for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++) increment(); }
        void operator-=(int _n) { for (int i = 0; i < _n; i--) decrement(); }
        void operator--() { decrement(); }
        void operator--(int) { decrement(); }
        void operator++() { increment(); }
        void operator++(int) { increment(); }

        // comparisons
        int operator==(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index == a.index; }
        int operator!=(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index != a.index; }
        int operator<(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index < a.index; }
        int operator>(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index > a.index; }
        int operator<=(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index <= a.index; }
        int operator>=(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { return index >= a.index; }
        int operator==(int _index) { return index == _index; }
        int operator!=(int _index) { return index != _index; }
        int operator<(int _index) { return index < _index; }
        int operator>(int _index) { return index > _index; }
        int operator<=(int _index) { return index <= _index; }
        int operator>=(int _index) { return index >= _index; }

        // value reference (retrieve value from parent class at this pos)
        _Tp& operator*() {
            return parent->value_real(index);
        }

        // get the key of the current index (or EMPTY)
        string get_key() {
            string key = parent->key_real(index);

            if (OCCUPIED(key)) return key;

            return EMPTY;
        }

        // copy
        void operator=(const stringmap<_Tp>::iterator& a) { 
            index = a.index; 
            parent = a.parent;
        }

        // misc
        void set_parent(stringmap<_Tp>* _parent) { parent = _parent; }

    };

    /* iterator ENDS */

    friend class iterator; // iterators can see our privates

    // copy constructor
    //
    stringmap(const stringmap<_Tp>& from) {

        _keys = from._keys;
        _values = from._values;

        probe = from.probe;
        size = from.size;
        size_idx = from.size_idx;
        minsize = from.minsize;
        maxsize = from.maxsize;

        filled = from.filled;
        undef_val = from.undef_val;

        // start efficiency off anew
        total_lookups = 0;
        total_attempts = 0;
    }

    // almost do-nothing constructor. just init to sane defaults.
    stringmap(_Tp _undef_val) :
        _keys(PRIMES[0], EMPTY),                
        _values(PRIMES[0], _undef_val),
        size_idx(0),
        minsize(PRIMES[0]),
        maxsize(PRIMES[MAX_PRIME_IDX]),
        undef_val(_undef_val),
        filled(0),
        total_attempts(0),
        total_lookups(0) {  

        // init size stuff
        // 
        size = PRIMES[size_idx];

        // initialize probe interval
        //
        probe = int(size/4) + 1;
    }

    // constructor without max or min size
    stringmap(int _startsize, _Tp _undef_val) : 
        _keys(0, EMPTY),                
        _values(0 , _undef_val),
        minsize(PRIMES[0]),
        maxsize(PRIMES[MAX_PRIME_IDX]),
        undef_val(_undef_val),
        filled(0) { 

        // init size stuff
        // 
        size_idx = nearest_prime_index(_startsize);
        size = PRIMES[size_idx];

        // init vectors
        //
        _keys.resize(size, EMPTY);
        _values.resize(size, _undef_val);

        // initialize probe interval
        //
        probe = int(size/4) + 1;

        // init statistics stuff
        //
        total_attempts = 0;
        total_lookups = 0;
    }

    // full constructor
    stringmap(int _minsize, int _maxsize, int _startsize, _Tp _undef_val) : 
        _keys(0, EMPTY),                
        _values(0 , _undef_val),
        minsize(_minsize),
        maxsize(_maxsize),
        undef_val(_undef_val),
        filled(0) { 

        // init size stuff
        // 
        size_idx = nearest_prime_index(_startsize);
        size = PRIMES[size_idx];

        // init vectors
        //
        _keys.resize(size, EMPTY);
        _values.resize(size, _undef_val);

        // initialize probe interval
        //
        probe = int(size/4) + 1;

        // init statistics stuff
        //
        total_attempts = 0;
        total_lookups = 0;
    }

    _Tp& get( string );         // get the value at a string key index
    _Tp& set( string, _Tp );    // set the value at a string key index

    // remove an element by its id, and return it (or undef)
    _Tp remove( string );

    // remove an element pointed to by iterator. 
    _Tp remove( stringmap<_Tp>::iterator );

    // remove an element given by real array location
    _Tp remove_real ( int );

    // "real" array accessors for key and value.  
    //
    string key_real( int idx ) { assert(idx < size && idx >= 0); return _keys[idx]; }
    _Tp& value_real( int idx ) { assert(idx < size && idx >= 0); return _values[idx]; }

    // see if a key exists
    //
    int exists( string key ) { return ( OCCUPIED(_keys[index_of(key)])); }

    // see if a value exists
    //
    int defined( string key ) { return (exists(key) && (_values[index_of(key)] != undef_val)); }

    // get the value at a string key index.  actually, this gets a value 
    // ref, and even more importantly, if you try to get a non-existant 
    // location, it will be created and set to undef_val! this allows you to
    // do things like map[new_key] = blah instead of calling set() !!
    //
    _Tp& operator[]( string );  // takes key, returns template object type (ref)

    // the only thing "tricky" this has to do is copy the vectors.  all other 
    // variables carry straight over.
    stringmap<_Tp>& operator=(stringmap<_Tp> from) {

        _keys = from._keys;
        _values = from._values;

        probe = from.probe;
        size = from.size;
        size_idx = from.size_idx;
        minsize = from.minsize;
        maxsize = from.maxsize;

        filled = from.filled;
        undef_val = from.undef_val;

        // start efficiency off anew
        total_lookups = 0;
        total_attempts = 0;

        return *this;
    }

    // some useful accessors
    // 
    int get_size() { return size; }
    int get_filled() { return filled; }

    // get the capacity of the underlying vectors
    //
    int get_capacity() { return _keys.capacity(); }

    // first and last occupied indices.  the iterator makes use of this.
    //
    int first_index();
    int last_index();

    // see how efficient this stringmap is. optimal return value is 1. if you 
    // have properly initialized the size, then you should get a value 
    // somehere around 1.7.
    //
    float get_efficiency() {
        if (total_lookups) {
            return ((float)total_attempts/(float)total_lookups); 
        }

        return 1;
    }

    /* iterator accessors */

    stringmap<_Tp>::iterator begin();
    stringmap<_Tp>::iterator end();
};

// find the first occupied index (or 0 if none)
//
template <class _Tp> 
int stringmap<_Tp>::first_index( ) {

    if (filled > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (OCCUPIED(_keys[i])) return i;
    } 

    return 0;
}

// find the last occupied index (or 0 if none)
//
template <class _Tp> 
int stringmap<_Tp>::last_index( ) {

    if (filled > 0) {
        for (int i = size - 1; i > 0; i--) 
            if (OCCUPIED(_keys[i])) return i;
    } 

    return 0;
}

// return a begin iterator
//
template <class _Tp> 
typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::begin( ) {

    if (filled == 0) {
        return stringmap<_Tp>::iterator(this, -1);
    } else {
        return stringmap<_Tp>::iterator(this, first_index());
    }
}

// return an end iterator
//
template <class _Tp> 
typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator stringmap<_Tp>::end( ) {

    if (filled == 0) {
        return stringmap<_Tp>::iterator(this, -1);
    } else {
        return stringmap<_Tp>::iterator(this, last_index() + 1);
    }
}

// the string hash function.  stolen from Kevin's code.
//
template <class _Tp>
unsigned int stringmap<_Tp>::hash_func( string k) {
    unsigned long h = 0;
    char const *p = k.c_str();

    while( *p ) {
        h = (h<<4) + *p++;
        unsigned long g = h & 0xF0000000L;
        if( g ) h ^= g >> 24;
        h &= ~g;
    }

    return h % size;
}

// get the index of a key in the hash table, taking into account
// collisions. performs linear probing.
//
template <class _Tp> 
unsigned int stringmap<_Tp>::index_of ( string _key ) {

    return index_of(_key, 0);   // this is only a "get" lookup
}

// actual implementation of above, with the following addition:
// if we are setting, we stop at vacated tombstones (-2) in addition to just
// tombstones (-1)
//
template <class _Tp> 
unsigned int stringmap<_Tp>::index_of ( string _key, int set ) {

    // run the key through the hash function to get the starting index
    //
    unsigned int index = hash_func(_key);

    // increment while the current index is not free or does not have 
    // the given key stored at it
    //
    int attempts = 1;

    // our chaining depends on whether or not we are seeking to add a new 
    // element to the hash.
    //
    if (set) {
        int vacated = -1;
        while (_keys[index] != _key && _keys[index] != EMPTY && attempts < size) {

            // if we found a vacated spot, "bookmark" it
            if (_keys[index] == VACATED && vacated == -1) vacated = index;

            // keep going
            index = (index + probe) % size;
            attempts++;
        }

        // if we didn't find the key but found a vacated position, use the 
        // vacated position.
        //
        if (attempts < size && !OCCUPIED(_keys[index]) && vacated != -1) {

            index = vacated;
        }

    } else {
        while (_keys[index] != _key && _keys[index] != EMPTY && attempts < size) {
            index = (index + probe) % size;
            attempts++;
        }
    }

    // full hash table if this is false!
    assert(attempts <= size);

    // keep track of lookup statistics
    //
    total_lookups++;
    total_attempts += attempts;

    return index;
}

// get a value from the hash vector.  returns the _Tp-typed undef value for 
// keys which are not found
//
template <class _Tp>
_Tp& stringmap<_Tp>::get ( string _key ) {

    unsigned int index = index_of(_key);

    return _values[index];
}

// []-style get, which also does a set for accessing un-defined "indices"
//
template <class _Tp>
_Tp& stringmap<_Tp>::operator[]( string _key ) {

    unsigned int index = index_of(_key);

    if (!OCCUPIED(_keys[index])) {

        // have to return this, as set could be setting at a different index
        // and we need a ref to the value at the correct index
        //
        return set(_key, undef_val);
    }

    return _values[index];
}

// remove an entry from the hash vector
//
template <class _Tp>
_Tp stringmap<_Tp>::remove ( string _key ) {

    unsigned int index = index_of(_key);

    return remove_real(index);
}

// remove an entry from the hash vector by table index, rather than key
//
template <class _Tp>
_Tp stringmap<_Tp>::remove_real( int index ) {

    string key = _keys[index];
    _Tp value = undef_val;

    // make sure something is here
    if (OCCUPIED(key)) {

        // grab the value
        value = _values[index];

        // clear the spot
        //
        _values[index] = undef_val;
        _keys[index] = VACATED;         // "vacated" tombstone

        // decrease filled count
        filled--;

        // check for table resize
        if (((float)filled/(float)size) < 0.25) {
            shrink();

            // calculate a new index for returning ref
            index = index_of(key);
        }
    }

    return value;
}

// set a value in the hash vector
// 
template <class _Tp>
_Tp& stringmap<_Tp>::set ( string _key, _Tp _val ) {

    unsigned int index = index_of(_key, 1);

    string key = _keys[index];

    // overwrite old value
    // 
    _values[index] = _val;

    // if new spot, see if we should grow. (EMPTY or VACATED)
    // 
    if ( !OCCUPIED(key) ) { 

        // first mark this spot with our key
        _keys[index] = _key;

        // increase filled count
        filled++;

        // check for table resize
        //
        if (((float)filled/(float)size) > 0.75) {

            grow();

            // calculate a new index for returning ref
            index = index_of(_key);
        }
    } 

    return _values[index];
}

// grow the hash vector
//
template <class _Tp>
void stringmap<_Tp>::grow() {

    // do nothing if there is no larger prime
    //
    if (PRIMES[size_idx+1] == 0) return;

    unsigned int nextsize = PRIMES[size_idx+1];

    // do nothing if we've hit our size limit
    if (nextsize > maxsize) return;

    // otherwise do the resize
    // 
    size_idx++;
    unsigned int old_size = size;
    size = nextsize;

    // copy the old vectors
    //
    vector <string> old_keys = _keys;
    vector <_Tp> old_values = _values;

    // resize keys and vals; set new half to defaults
    //  
    _keys.resize(size, EMPTY);
    _values.resize(size, undef_val);

    // clear out old portion (~ 1st half)
    //
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {
        _keys[i] = EMPTY;
        _values[i] = undef_val;
    }

    // new probe interval
    //
    probe = int(size/4) + 1;

    // hash old keys and values into resized vector
    //
    for (i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {

        if (OCCUPIED(old_keys[i])) {  // ignore all tombstoned entries
            unsigned int index = index_of(old_keys[i]);
            _keys[index] = old_keys[i];
            _values[index] = old_values[i];
        }
    }

    // unquote this to care about resizing overhead in efficiency stats
    //
    total_attempts += old_size; // at least this many ops in the copying
    total_lookups -= old_size;  // these aren't "external" lookups
}

// shrink the hash vector
// 
template <class _Tp> 
void stringmap<_Tp>::shrink () {

    // do nothing if there is no smaller prime
    //
    if (size_idx == 0) return;

    unsigned int nextsize = PRIMES[size_idx-1];

    // do nothing if we've hit our size limit
    if (nextsize < minsize) return;

    // otherwise do the resize
    // 
    size_idx--;
    unsigned int old_size = size;
    size = nextsize;

    // copy the old vectors
    //
    vector <string> old_keys = _keys;
    vector <_Tp> old_values = _values;

    // resize keys and vals
    //  
    _keys.resize(size, EMPTY);
    _values.resize(size, undef_val);

    // set to defaults
    //
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        _keys[i] = EMPTY;
        _values[i] = undef_val;
    }

    // new probe interval
    //
    probe = int(size/4) + 1;

    // hash old keys and values into resized vector
    //
    for (i = 0; i < old_size; i++) {

        if (OCCUPIED(old_keys[i])) {  // ignore all tombstoned entries
            unsigned int index = index_of(old_keys[i]);
            _keys[index] = old_keys[i];
            _values[index] = old_values[i];
        }
    }

    // unquote this to care about resizing overhead in efficiency stats
    //
    total_attempts += old_size; // at least this many ops in the copying
    total_lookups -= old_size;  // these aren't "external" lookups
}



#endif
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need typename:

```
typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator begin();
typename stringmap<_Tp>::iterator end();
```

The reason being being that `iterator` is dependent on what _Tp is, so the compiler can't be sure it's a [typename](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) unless you tell it. I'd recommend `typedef`'s to get that stuff out of the way:

```
typedef stringmap<_Tp> container_type;
typedef typename container_type::iterator iterator_type;

iterator_type begin();
iterator_type end();
```

Also, keep in mind that an underscore followed by a capital letter is reserved for the compiler, and yours looks especially common for compilers to use. I'd recommend simply using `T`. It's much more common in user-created code, and easier to read.